# How to fast scope and fire in cs 1.6?

Tags: counter-strike

I have been trying to improve my awp skills and found some cool tips on the internet already. I am much better with awp these days, but I still suck when compared to some of the guys who I play against daily. Of course in the pub games there are some hackers too, but I don't care about them.

This is what I did to improve my awp skills

- Set hud_fastswitch 1 command in the console to switch between weapons quickly
- Zoom and fire when I see an enemy in the center of my screen (I sometimes do it so fast that it appears like scope less fire which is part of the tip/trick)
- Switch to other weapons (I usually press 2 for pistol) and immediately press 1 to switch back to the mag and repeat 2 & 3

However, this does not seem to be enough. I know it takes a little time between each fire but I've seen people do it (killing two in a row) so fast in no time. Sometimes I suspect they are hacking but I am not sure how they do it (maybe using scripts).

Can some tell me legal way to do this?

Comment: you may as well try using `Q` instead of `2` and then `1` again. `Q` would switch you back to your previous weapon, so pressing it twice in a row will do the same, but just a little tiny bit faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Set hud_fastswitch 1 command in the console to switch between weapons quickly

This doesn't allow you to shoot faster any more. It used to in earlier versions of CS, but was removed prior to 1.6. You don't need to switch weapons unless you want to run away faster or think you'll need to use your pistol.

> - Zoom and fire when I see an enemy in the center of my screen (I some time do it so fast that it appears like scope less fire which is part of the tip/trick)

This is called quickscoping. The timing is difficult at first, but you want to right click and then left click almost immediately. If you're aiming properly (which is hard without practice), it's a kill, the bullet will be accurate even though you're not scoped in.

> I know it takes a little time to between each fire but I saw some do it (killing two in a row) so fast in no time.

The way they're doing this is to fire the first shot normally when scoped in, and then (without switching weapons) immediately aim and fire the next shot. That second shot will be accurate even though you're not zoomed in, but the aiming part is difficult, especially from longer ranges.

I suggest practicing in a Deatmatch server, there will be plenty of chances to work on quickscoping.

Note: There's a bug in CS where quickscoped shots won't put a bullet hole in the right place. Your shots are accurate if you're quickscoping right, so don't worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

with AWM it helps to put a transparent sticker with a red dot in the center of the screen... so you know where the gun fires without a zoom :)

I also used Q for weapons switching ... that did the work...